# Ckeditor обрезает javascript

Tags: jquery, html, ckeditor

Всем привет.

Подключил CKEditor.
Появилась вот какая проблема. Вставляю

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
```

Хочу, чтобы выглядело, как текст. Первый раз загружает нормально. При повторной загрузке из БД эта строка пропадает. Что за прикол?

Comment: Ну и вы чего хотели? Всё правильно, а то накопируют текстов со всякими бяками)

Посмотрите мой ответ: http://hashcode.ru/questions/240142#240213

Comment: Вставил ваш код в config.js Ничего не изменилось. Все так же обрезает при повторной загрузке.

Comment: @duddeniska а, извиняюсь, вопрос с утра не так прочитал.
Если вы хотите, чтобы запись выглядела как текст, то в "источнике" запись должна выглядеть так:

    &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;

То есть дополнительно ничего не нужно изменять в редакторе. 
Возможно, у вас что-то не так происходит при сохранении.

Comment: Прикол в том, что сохраняет в бд нормально, на странице показывает так, как нужно, но потом я хочу отредактировать текст, выгружаю в Ckeditor и он удаляет код! ((((

Comment: @duddeniska посмотрите, какой код он выгружает в редактор? Если там идет запись как тег, то редактор её будет вырезать. Если как я привел пример, то всё будет ок.

Comment: Прикол в том, что вообще пусто, просто пусто, а если это html, то он показывает его как html страницу, но не код!

Comment: @duddeniska проверьте функцию сохранения, правильно ли она сохраняет данные.

Comment: в БД сохраняет правильно, так, как нужно, проблема именно при выгрузке в Ckeditor, когда хочу отредактировать запись! (